# Combining scripts import/export

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

<script type="module"  src="greenZombie.js"></script>

<script type="module"  src="marcusSprite.js"></script>
```

I have these 3 scripts, and i want to draw them in my main.js

```
export { CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT,ctx };

const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width = 1200;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height = 600;

// Define your game loop function
function gameLoop() {
   // Clear the canvas
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

  

   // Request the next frame
   requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

// Start the game loop
gameLoop();
```

When i try to draw them in, i get that they are not defined, but they are in my other 2 scripts. How do i import/export so that my main script gets those objects without having issues?

Answer (score 0):

To import everything from greenZombie.js and marcusSprite.js you can write the following at the top of the main.js:

```
import * as GreenZombie from './greenZombie.js';
import * as MarcusSprite from './marcusSprite.js';
```

You can use GreenZombie & MarcusSprite objects to call further functions or anything.